# Does the Photos App register a URL Handler on the iPhone?

Tags: iphone

I have read the Apple documentation.  They list the apps registered, yet in their example they use a handler not mentioned.
https://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/ApplicationEnvironment/chapter_3_section_6.html

This post attempts to list the handlers.  But it too appears incomplete since the iPod handler is not listed.
http://quinagh.com/applookup/index.php/2009/01/07/iphone-apps-with-special-url-shortcuts/

Is there a complete list available?  Does anyone know if the Photos app has a registered handler or not for certain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is, afaik, no way to tell beyond those that are documented.

Answer (score 1):

http://arstechnica.com/apple/guides/2009/03/building-services-into-iphone-applications.ars